# embedding a form view in a parent view

Tags: php, symfony

My Symfony app view layout is a three level hierarchy, such that there is the baseview.html.twig and then the child of that is layout.html.twig and then the child of layout view is X,Y,Z,.... .html.twig. I wanted to pass in a form to the layout.html.twig, however where in my controller should I do this?

Here's some code to make it more clear of the hierarchy. In the bottom base line view I have the following:

```
{% extends 'AppMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

and then in layout.html.twig I have:

```
  {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

so I wanted to pass in a formView to my layout.html.twig, the question is how??

Answer (score 0):

Use blocks [like block content in documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html)

For Ex:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
  {{form_widget(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Now content block will be replaced in parent by your block.